# How to embed functions into functions in javascript like this?

Tags: javascript, function

I've just met with a very interesting task to solve, but I can't do it myself.

Make a function which do the following input!

```
console.log(foo(4)(5)(6)); // output: 120
```

The solution is not this:

```
function foo(number1,number2,number3){
  return number1 * number2 * number3;
}
```

In theory it has to use nested functions.

Comment: Are you doing a quiz? I'll give you a hint anyway: the foo function has to return another function, which also returns a function. By the way, nested functions are not considered good practice, maybe you can just answer that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called **currying**. You need to return function which it's case returns a function which returns the total. Here we also use a term called [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
function foo(a){
  return function(b)  {
     return function(c){
       return a * b * c;
     }
   } 
}

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6));
```

**With ES6 syntax**

```js
var foo = a => b => c => a*b*c;

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6));
```

**For infinite levels you can do**

```js
function foo(value){
  infinite.total = value;
  
  function infinite(val) {
     infinite.total *= val;
     return infinite;
  }
  
  infinite.toString = function() { return infinite.total; }
  
  return infinite;
  
}

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6)(7));

var total = foo(4)(5)(6)(7);
console.log(total);
```

But this will output the total in that cases, when `toString()` is called explicitly or implicitly

Comment: It's called `currying` !

Comment: It was too easy. Very nice! Thx!

Comment: Is it possible to do an infinite level of currying? Can I make a function which will work for 'foo(5)' 'foo(5)(6)' and 'foo(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)' without hard coding 8 functions?

Comment: @Keatinge see the updated part and also Nina's answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use an approach for any length of repeated calls of the function with returning a function and an implementation of `toString` method.

```js
var foo = function(value) {
    function fn(a) {
        fn.value *= a;
        return fn;
    }
    fn.value = value;
    fn.toString = function () { return fn.value; };
    return fn;
}

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6));
console.log(foo(42));
console.log(foo(42)(44));
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach!

Answer (score 1):

try with `currying`:

```
function foo(number) {
  return function(number2) {
    return function(number3) {
      return number * number2  number3;
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo(5)(6)(7));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mv9bm3tL/1/

More information : https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

```
You need nested functions - currying;

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6)); // output: 120


let first = foo(4);
let second = first(5);
let last = second(6);

console.log(last);

function foo(number1,number2,number3){
  return function(number2){
    return function(number3){
      return number1 * number2 * number3;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Closures in javascript will help you to achieve this.

```
function foo(a){
  return function(b){
    return function(c){
      return a*b*c;
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6)); //will return 120
```

Answer (score 1):

Using arrow functions;

```js
var foo = a => b => c => a*b*c;

console.log(foo(4)(5)(6));
```